# String is not a function when loading backbone render function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

The below is a piece of code implemented on backbone.

`new staffListViewN().render(qualifiedStaff,this.id);`

I am getting error like

"String is not a function"

below is the implementation of the above render function.

```
staffListViewN = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#staffs-list',
    render:function(stafflistParam,id)
    {
      var stafflist = stafflistParam;
      var ref = this;

      if(validate.variable(stafflist))
      {
        agentList = {agentList:stafflist};               
        ref.$el.html(staffListTemplate);
      }
     }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an indication of what line you are getting the error on? I'd guess validate.variable is a string, and you are trying to invoke it like its a function.

Comment: HI I am getting error in this line(not exactly to identify the positon). But when calling this line of code.